# understanding how apache spark functionality overlaps with other popular sql query engine and big data frameworks

Tags: bigdata, apache-spark, apache-kafka

i m really interested in  seeing how functionality of diff big data tools overlaps between apache spark, apache drill, cloudera impala, trino, presto db.

i m confused about the difference btw"distributed sql query engine" and apache spark. Apparently some tools like presto db serve as capping on top of various data sources - s3, hdfs, sql server, mysql, postgresql. And this is the only primary role of sql query engine?
sql query engine != sql db, correct?

So far, apache spark seems to be the most versatile thing as it offers ML training, sql querying without moving data and computing query over streaming data, while sql engines are primarly used just to quickly aggregate data from various data sources - is it correct?

from the [presto](https://www.alluxio.io/learn/presto/query/#:%7E:text=A%20distributed%20SQL%20query%20engine,Cloudera%20Impala%2C%20and%20Apache%20Spark.) db page: `A distributed SQL query engine will allow you to query data from a variety of data sources like Hadoop, AWS S3, NoSQL, MySQL, and more, or data from multiple data sources within a single query.`

what tools can we use interchangeably - if they belong to same type?

I made a short summary of functionality and roles of each mentioned instrument based on its official website.

**distributed sql query engine** - dont store data itself:

- presto db: opensource fast,scalable **SQL query engine**
- trino: fast distributed **SQL query engine** for big data analytics
- apache drill: schema-free **SQL Query Engine** for Hadoop, NoSQL
- apache impala:  opensource MPP **SQL query engine** for data stored in Apache Hadoop

sql/nosql **database** - stores data in a cluster of worker nodes:

- apache druid: a high performance, real-time analytics **database**
- apache ignite - distributed database mngmt system(dbms) aka **db**
- apache cassandra - opensource NoSQL distributed **database**
- apache hbase opensource nosql distributed **db**
- apache kudu - open source distributed data storage engine(db? or not?)

stream processing framework(can do ml training, streaming analytics, sql on streams):

- apache spark
- apache samza
- apache kafka
- apache storm

my question is that distributed sql query engines != sql database engine(not a db) and distributed sql query engine works as just a tool to join data from data sources; while apache spark is more of a versatile computation engine (though it has some limited ingestion features similar to any sql query engine), correct?